# Why does this date parse not work in C# .net 1.1?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-1.1

```
private bool ValidDateCheck(){

 bool _isValid = true;
 try{
  DateTime.Parse("07/&*/2009");
  DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime("07/&*/2009");
 }
 catch{
  _isValid = false;
 }
 return _isValid;
}
```

How does the above code not throw an exception?

Comment: Throws an exception for me in .NET 3.5

Comment: First you want to declare in "" RT?.I am getting compile time error

Comment: .net 1.1, within a try catch block

Comment: I get a BadFormat exception in 3.5 as well.

Comment: When you say code, do you mean the Convert.ToDateTime part or the entire block?  I hope it is the former, because the latter is quite obvious!

Comment: ConverToDateTime part. How does the value "05/&*/2009" convert to a valid DateTime, or get parsed to a valid datetime?

Comment: How do you know it is being converted to a valid DateTime? Is the method returning true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the [.NET 1.1 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326714(VS.71).aspx):

> The string s is parsed using the
>   formatting information in a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo initialized for the
>   current culture.
>
> This method attempts to parse s
>   completely and avoid throwing
>   FormatException. **It ignores
>   unrecognized data if possible and
>   fills in missing month, day, and year
>   information with the current time.** If
>   s contains only a date and no time,
>   this method assumes 12 A.M. Any
>   leading, inner, or trailing white
>   space character in s is ignored.
>
> Parameter s must contain the
>   representation of a date and time in
>   one of the formats described in the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo topic.

I am unable to test this as the earliest version I can build with in VS2008 is 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't throw an exception because exceptions are thrown at run time, and this code never runs.  I know it never runs because there's no way it would compile with single quotes for the string literals.  You need to use double quotes for the strings.

If the single quotes are just a typo, please edit the question and I'll take another look.

Comment: It's also missing semicolons. :)

Comment: sorry about that, it is in double quotes, it was a misprint on myside

Comment: private bool ValidDateCheck(){

   bool _isValid = true;   
   try{
    DateTime.Parse("10/&*/2009");
    DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime("10/&*/2009");
   }
   catch{
    _isValid = false;
   }
   return _isValid;
  }

Comment: @Martin: it made more sense when I posted it.  At the time there was a different code snippet with no mention of .net 1.1, and so it looked like maybe was supposed to be a trick question.

Answer (score 0):

use [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: His code is not throwing an exception, which is the question at hand here.  TryParse will not help him.

Comment: I understood the question that the code did raise an exception, and OP wants to avoid it. 1.1 comment and tag have been added after my answer.